# Existence of inverse of sum of matrices

Tags: matrices

Suppose you have $I + A + B$ where $I$ is the identity matrix and $A,B$ are square matrices with rank 1. Does the inverse, $(I + A + B)^{-1}$, exist? If so, how would you evaluate it?

Comment: It doesn't necessarily exist, not even in $1\times 1$ matrices.

Comment: It is enough to take A and B such that the sum of one element on the diagonal of the matrix C:= A+B is -1.

Answer (score 4):

The inverse doesn't necessarily exist: take
$$A=B=\operatorname{diag}\left(-\frac12,0,\ldots,0\right)$$